# FPDF Display Data From Database Outside The Table Doesn't Work

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm displaying a data outside and inside the table. When I tried to call the data on inside the table, it works perfectly fine but when I call it outside, it suddenly doesn't show. This part right here...

```
$pdf->MultiCell(194,4,"STORM SURGE INFORMATION",0,'C', false);
$pdf->Cell(191,4,"STORM SURGE: WARNING # ",0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-136,4,$fetch['warning'],0,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(172,4,"FOR: TYPHOON ",0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-119,4,$fetch['typhoon'],0,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(175,4,"ISSUED AT ",0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-135,4,$fetch['date'],0,1,'C');
```

My PDF currently look like this.

[image]

Can somebody help me figure out what is wrong or missing with my codes?

```
<?php

require("con.php");

$sql="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ssh REGEXP '^[^A-Za-z0-9]' ASC, ssh DESC";

$records=mysql_query($sql);
$fetch = $records[0];

require("library/fpdf.php");

class PDF extends FPDF{
  function Header(){
  }
  function Footer(){
  }
}

$pdf = new PDF('p', 'mm', 'Legal');
$title = 'Storm Surge Warning';
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,40);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);

$pdf->MultiCell(194,4,"STORM SURGE INFORMATION",0,'C', false);
$pdf->Cell(191,4,"STORM SURGE: WARNING # ",0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-136,4,$fetch['warning'],0,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(172,4,"FOR: TYPHOON ",0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-119,4,$fetch['typhoon'],0,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(175,4,"ISSUED AT ",0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-135,4,$fetch['date'],0,1,'C');

$pdf->Ln(1);

$pdf->SetBorders(array('LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'TLR'));
$pdf->SetWidths(array(25, 27, 35, 54, 53));
$pdf->SetAligns(array('C', 'C', 'C', 'L', 'L'));

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);

$pdf->Row(array("SS Height",
            "Provinces",
            "Low Lying Coastal Areas in the Municipalities of:",
            "IMPACTS",
            "ADVICE/Actions to Take"), 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 11);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){
  $pdf->Row(array($row['ssh'],
  $row['provi'],
  $row['muni'],
  $row['impact'],
  $row['advice']), 1);
  }

$pdf->SetBorders(array('T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'));
$pdf->Row(array('','','','',''), 1, false, 1);

$pdf->OutPut();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Early in your code you are fetching a row of data but you aren't adding the row to the PDF with that data before you start your `while` loop. Right after you set the font and before the `while` loop make the add the `$pdf->Row` bit shown below.

```
$pdf->MultiCell(194,4,"STORM SURGE INFORMATION",0,'C', false); 
$pdf->Cell(191,4,"STORM SURGE: WARNING # ",0,0,'C'); 
$pdf->Cell(-136,4,$fetch['warning'],0,1,'C'); 
$pdf->Cell(172,4,"FOR: TYPHOON ",0,0,'C'); 
$pdf->Cell(-119,4,$fetch['typhoon'],0,1,'C'); 
$pdf->Cell(175,4,"ISSUED AT ",0,0,'C'); 
$pdf->Cell(-135,4,$fetch['date'],0,1,'C');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 11);

$pdf->Row(array($fetch['ssh'],
    $fetch['provi'],
    $fetch['muni'],
    $fetch['impact'],
    $fetch['advice']), 1);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){
  $pdf->Row(array($row['ssh'],
  $row['provi'],
  $row['muni'],
  $row['impact'],
  $row['advice']), 1);
}
```

Comment: Still the same. @Dave

Comment: Based on the code you posted that is in fact the solution. Are you sure that your query is producing the results that you expect and that the row you think is missing is really in the results? That row is clearly retrieving a row of data from the results of the query but you are never doing anything with it which means that when you start the `while` loop you are really starting on the 2nd result.

Comment: Changed it into `$fetch = $records[0];` and it fixed it however I'm displaying a data outside the table and it's not working. This part right here `$pdf->MultiCell(194,4,"STORM SURGE INFORMATION",0,'C', false);
$pdf->Cell(191,4,"STORM SURGE: WARNING # ",0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-136,4,$fetch['warning'],0,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(172,4,"FOR: TYPHOON ",0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-119,4,$fetch['typhoon'],0,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(175,4,"ISSUED AT ",0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-135,4,$fetch['date'],0,1,'C');` @Dave

Comment: OK, you changed your code in the original question which changes things completely. The code in your comment was not there before. Based on your changes to the original I've updated my answer which should resolve your problem.

Comment: sadly it still doesn't display it :(

Comment: You modified your question again. It's almost impossible to try and troubleshoot what may be going wrong when you keep changing the question. Right after `$fetch = $records[0];` add `var_dump($fetch);` and edit your question to add the results.

Comment: I got an error saying `NULL 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Task\library\fpdf.php:404 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Task\library\fpdf.php(1196): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Task\library\fpdf.php(1132): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Task\pdf.php(148): FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Task\library\fpdf.php on line 404` @Dave

Comment: Just `exit;` right after the var_dump to stop things.

Comment: This is how my code looks like `var_dump($fetch);
exit;` and when I run it it only says `NULL`. It doesn't display anything but that word. @Dave